# CodeIgniter: Include a controller outside the application environment

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

So basically, I would like to load a CodeIgniter controller contents outside CodeIgniter's environment, that is, from a traditional PHP page.

I have tried the following but it doesn't suit my requirements:

```
<?php
require('/application/controller/error?type=not_found');
?>
```

It gives the following error:

```
Message: require(/application/controller/error?type=not_found): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

To clarify, I'm trying to change the default /application/errors/error_404.php page contents to this so it will display the custom HTTP 404 error page I've built in the "error" controller & view.

The problem is, The pages under /application/errors/ are treated as normal PHP pages by CodeIgniter which means I can't use `$this->load-view('error');` inside the `error_404.php` page.

I would also appreciate other suggestions for ways to create custom error pages in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the 404 page in the route.php page in the application/config folder:

```
 $route['404_override'] = 'your-error-controller/your-error-view';
```

This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.

I might be confused at your question but the routes.php gives you a place where you can point the 404 page to a custom view.

Comment: Thank you, it perfectly works! Now I have another question, is it possible to use the "routes.php" file to assign custom views to the other 3 errors CodeIgniter has? the general, database and PHP error pages.

Comment: Thats a good question, I have not tried. As far as overriding the actual routes I do not know. But what I would do is just back up the other 3 error views Codeigniter has and then customize the existing one. I would search around for more answers though, or ask a new question! You can check out https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Editing the 3 error pages to redirect to a controller is my current approach, but I wish there's a more consistent way that's based on editing the routes (just like we just did for the 404 error) rather than editing the pages.